# Primefaces - datatable column filter textbox not appearing

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I'm using PF 4.0 and I have a datatable that is lazily loaded and i'm trying to add a filter textbox to the "name" column, but the textbox is not appearing. What am I missing?

```
...
<p:dataTable var="user" value="#{userGroupBacking.users}" editable="true" id="userTable" paginator="true" rows="20"  
    paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport}  {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink}" lazy="true"
    filteredValue="#{userGroupBacking.filteredUsers}" >

    <p:ajax event="rowEdit" listener="#{userGroupBacking.onEdit}" /> 

    <p:column headerText="User" filterBy="#{user.name}" filterMatchMode="contains">
        <h:outputText value="#{user.name}" />
    </p:column>
...
```

backing bean:

```
@ManagedBean(name="userGroupBacking")
@ViewScoped
public class UserGroupBacking {

@ManagedProperty(value="#{accessBacking}")
    private AccessBacking accessBacking;
    public void setAccessBacking(AccessBacking accessBacking) {
        this.accessBacking = accessBacking;
    }

@PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        this.ds = databaseBacking.getDs();
        if(isLoggedIn()) {
            loadData();
        }
    }

/**
     * Checks that the user is logged in
     * @return
     */
    public boolean isLoggedIn() {
        return accessBacking.isHasAccess();
    }

public LazyDataModel<User> getUsers() {
        return users;
    }
    public List<Group> getGroups() {
        return groups;
    }
    public List<Group> getSelectedGroups() {
        return selectedGroups;
    }
    public List<SelectItem> getGroupsAsSelectItems() {
        return groupsAsSelectItems;
    }
    public List<SelectItem> getUsersAsSelectItems() {
        return usersAsSelectItems;
    }
    public String getNewGroup() {
        return newGroup;
    }
    public void setNewGroup(String newGroup) {
        this.newGroup = newGroup;
    }
    public List<User> getFilteredUsers() {
        return filteredUsers;
    }
    public void setFilteredUsers(List<User> filteredUsers) {
        this.filteredUsers = filteredUsers;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your problem only with filtering right..Whether your dataTable retrieving values from bean class..

Comment: The filter box doesn't show up to even type anything into.

Comment: @Catfish - Have you tried an older version of PF?

Comment: @kolossus i just checked PF 3.5 and it works there. The filtering seems to be busted in 4.0.

Comment: @Catfish - figures. 4.0 is still quite bleeding edge. Reporting a bug?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I figured it out. It seems that in PF 4.0, you need the filterBy code to change from:

```
<p:column headerText="User" filterBy="#{user.name}" filterMatchMode="contains">
    <h:outputText value="#{user.name}" />
</p:column>
```

to:

```
<p:column headerText="User" filterBy="name" filterMatchMode="contains">
    <h:outputText value="#{user.name}" />
</p:column>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am just curious, is this the actual code you have in your page. Cause it should wrapped up inside `<p:cellEditor>` as shown in primefaces showcase

http://www.primefaces.org/showcase-labs/ui/datatableRowEditing.jsf

some thing like

```
<p:column headerText="Model" style="width:30%">  
            <p:cellEditor>  
                <f:facet name="output">  
                    <h:outputText value="#{car.model}" />  
                </f:facet>  
                <f:facet name="input">  
                    <p:inputText value="#{car.model}" style="width:100%"/>  
                </f:facet>  
            </p:cellEditor>  
        </p:column>
```

Comment: I have another column that has p:cellEditor in it, but this particular column I'm just trying to get the filter textbox to appear.